# React JS Autocomplete Sublime Text 3

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I wonder what is the extension to make an autocomplete for React in Sublime Text 3, as you can see from the picture below that they have an autocomplete for `createClass` and `createElement`.

Can someone give me a suggestion what package should I download to have an autocomplete like that? So far I always manually typed it and is quite troublesome since it's a long word.

[image]

Comment: That screenshot looks like Visual Studio Code

Comment: @tgreen oh sorry i should have mention it, yes that is from visual studio code, but i believe sublime also has something that similar like that

Comment: @Mirza, did you found any fix for your problem. I am also looking for the same, but couldn't find any?